# How to read higher size DB from MySQL using Polars and ConnectoX?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, python-polars

I'm new to Polars. I'm trying to get data from MySQL using polars for one of my project. here I have made a connection and trying to retrieve some sample data from a table.

[image]

on executing this query it returns some of index data not the actual data from table.
what could be the reason for it ?
it should actually give an output as this:

[image]

please guide me how to make a connection in between MySQL and Polars.
because i have about 250M records stored in a table on which i have to do some of data analysis
I have tried this command using pandas, pymysql:

```
df_pol = pl.from_pandas(pd.read_sql(f'SELECT *FROM complete_list_rolled_up',con))
```

here I have got an Memory Error while reading data from data using pandas statement .

In an another case: using connectorX to retrieve data from MySQL as follows:

```
cx.read_sql(uri,'SELECT *FROM complete_list_rolled_up limit 5')
```

I'm able to read the same table using connectorX as above. but in output it shows b in every entry such as b'unknown', b'49499494' etc etc.

[image]

What could be the reasons for getting this kind of outputs reading the data from MySQL using polars/connectorX?

Any idea on making DB connections between MySQL and Polars?

Comment: Have you tried adding `protocol= text` in `read_sql` function as described here: https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x/discussions/165

Comment: Yes i have used protocol as text and but still the same output as indexes

Comment: That's odd.. Not sure if this is related or not but read_sql takes a connection object not a connection string. Try making a conne tion object with sqlalchemy and passing that connection variable to read_sql

Comment: ```my_sql_engine = create_engine(
        url="mysql+pymysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}".format(
            db_user_name , db_pass_word, db_host, db_port, db_name
        )) ``` ```with my_sql_engine.connect() as con:
    pl.read_sql('SELECT *FROM bolton_complete_list_rolled_up limit 5',con)``` on executing it is gives an error: AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @rayad do you have any updates/comments on it ?

Comment: @cbilot do you have any comments on it? Can you please try to connect mySql using poalrs and check how the output of table is ??

Comment: Interesting error. Can't say for certain without the full traceback but I think that will be coming from within pandas itself. But before we do that i think you don't have to use .connect() in the with statement. Try removing it and try again

Comment: @rayad i tried without mentioning .connect() and this time it is giving an error: ``` AttributeError: __enter__ ```

Comment: @rayad could you please connect to mysql at your end and test it ?

Comment: This could be caused by columns which are of VARBINARY type. What are the types of the columns in your MySQL table? Can you include the output of `DESCRIBE <tablename>` in your question?